# Subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & y \end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p}) : y \in \mathbb{F}_{p}^{*}, x \in \mathbb{F}_{p} \right\}. $ Describe a subgroup $H \leq G : |H| = p$ and show that there is only one such $H$.

The subgroup I obtained is $H = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})  : x \in \mathbb{F}_{p} \right\}$, which is of order $p$, but I am unable to show it is unique.

Comment: Small error, if $x=0$ then $H$ doesn't have order $p$. What can you say about the order of groups generated where $y \neq 1$?

Comment: The group as a set has order $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G$ has $p(p-1)$ elements, so any such $H$ is a Sylow-$p$ subgroup of $G$. The number of such subgroups divides $[G:H]=p-1$ and is also congruent to $1$ mod $p$, hence must be equal to $1$.

Comment: Yes, it is a unique sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything as deep as Sylow.

Since $y\in\mathbb{F}_p$ has order diving $p-1$ we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x\\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}^{p}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & *\\
0 & y^p
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & *\\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This tells us the only matrices of order dividing $p$ are those with $y=1$.